# Error with Basic Multiple Class Java Program

Tags: java

I'm trying to take two floating point values, see which one is greater, and return true or false.  This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Four_Ten
{
    public static void main(String []args){
        double num1, num2 = 0;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a floating point value:");
        num1 = scan.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Enter another floating point value:");
        num2 = scan.nextFloat();
        System.out.println(calcGreater(num1, num2));
    }

    public double calcGreater(double a, double b){
        boolean greater = false;
        if (a > b){
            greater = true;
        }
        if (b > a){
            greater = false;
        }
        return greater;
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

`non-static method calcGreater(double, double) cannot be referenced from a static context`

How can I fix this?

Comment: What do you think the error message means?

Comment: Google the error. You will find the solution.

Comment: Read upon 'static' keyword in Java..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`public double calcGreater(double a, double b)` is not a `static` method so you can't call `non-static` method from `static` method.add `static` key word to `calcGreater()` as follows

```
public static double calcGreater(double a, double b)
```

Or

instantiate the object and call method as follows

```
Four_Ten a=new Four_Ten();
a.calcGreater(double a, double b);
```

Not only that: **return type mismatch**

```
public double calcGreater(double a, double b){ // expected return type double 
    boolean greater = false;
    if (a > b){
        greater = true;
    }
    if (b > a){
        greater = false;
    }
    return greater;  // you are returning boolean
}
```

Comment: How do I return a boolean and pass the two floating point values into the class at the same time?  Is this possible?

Comment: If you want to do so, use custom object(create a class with both return type) and return that.

Comment: This makes much more sense.  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Four_Ten
{
    public static void main(String []args){
    double num1, num2 = 0;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a floating point value:");
    num1 = scan.nextFloat();
    System.out.println("Enter another floating point value:");
    num2 = scan.nextFloat();
    Four_Ten obj=new Four_Ten();
    System.out.println(obj.calcGreater(num1, num2));
}

public double calcGreater(double a, double b){
    boolean greater = false;
    if (a > b){
        greater = true;
    }
    if (b > a){
        greater = false;
    }
    return greater;
}
}
```

Comment: Expected return type is `double` while return `boolen`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the keyword `static` and it's a `boolean` not a `double` -

```
public static boolean calcGreater(double a, double b){
  // return (a > b); /* why not a > b? */
  boolean greater = false;
  if (a > b){
    greater = true;
  }
  if (b > a){
    greater = false;
  }
  return greater;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an object of class Four_Ten and then call the method like

```
Four_Ten obj = new Four_Ten();
obj.calcGreater(num1,num2);
```

You're getting error because non-static members can't be directly accessed by static members. In this case main() is static and calcGreater() is non - static so you need a object to access non-static function calcGreater() from static main() function.